# why using NSOperation, GCD or performSelectorInBackground I can't take snapshot of UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview

I'm trying to take screenshotot of my `UIView` with method below. It works only if I don't try to do this in "background". But i need it in background, because each time it fires, I got horrible ui responsibility - nothing works for a few seconds.

This method works, but it stucks forever, with `mach_msg_trap` message when I pause it.

```
-(void)takeShoot{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        float height;
        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
            height = 600;
        }else{
            height = 500;
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, height), YES, 0.6);

        [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, -60, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];

                self.sharedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    });
}
```

When I was fire it in `NSOperation` it get even worse -it just won't do this without any reason.
And third method `performSelectorInBackground` is just rubbish, if I fire it method each time when `uiwebview` finish loading, then there will bee billion threads and thats I think isn't good at all.

So, how can I take screenshoot in background(not on `mainThread`), not killing or freezing anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must take screenshots on the main thread. This is the only thread where the UI is stable.

If you have problems for several seconds, I suspect you have some other problem going on that this is just exposing. The most likely is other UIKit calls you're making on background threads. That's not supported and would lead to the symptom you describe.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The only working method is this.
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, .1 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){}); but when it fires sometimes uiwebview scrolling response is poor. Any ideas how to prevent that?

Comment: Fancy things with UIWebView are always challenging. It doesn't behave like normal views. I would test against iOS8 which has a lot of improvements (not that this fixes your problem, but at least it helps you understand it better). But you can also look at first calling `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` and then taking an image off of the returned view. You *might* even get away with doing the final render on a background thread, though it probably isn't supported so…danger.